# Error (if/else dentro de un foreach) Razor

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estoy agregando una condicional dentro de un foreach y al momento de ejecutar me sale error de que falta una llave. Cuando quito el código, funciona sin ningún problema, pero con la condicional if se cae, y si agrego el else, el lenguaje no lo reconoce, lo toma como si fuera HTML, estoy que le agrego una arroba "@" para ver si se quita el error y nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

```
    @model IEnumerable<wsCharlas.Models.ClsCharla>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MostrarCharlasExternos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<img style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px" src="~/Imagenes/ejemploBanner.jpg"/>

<h2 class="titulo-charla-externo"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>LISTADO DE CHARLAS DISPONIBLES:</h2>

<div class="container-principal">


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <div class="c-datos d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
            <div class="c-dependencia">
                <h6>Dependencia: </h6>
                @Html.DropDownList("sed", (SelectList)ViewBag.allSedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class="c-meses">
                <h6>Meses: </h6>
                @Html.DropDownList("sed", (SelectList)ViewBag.allSedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
    }

    <div class="container container-lista d-flex flex-row justify-content-between flex-wrap">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            string hora = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hora_Charla).ToString();

            string hora_modificada = "p.m.";

            if (
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("00") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("01") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("02") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("03") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("04") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("05") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("06") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("07") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("08") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("09") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("10") ||
            hora.Substring(0, 2).Equals("11"))
            {
                hora_modificada = "a.m.";
            }

            <div class="card" style="width: 21.5rem;">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/286/180" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen Aleatoria">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align:center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.titulo_Charla)</h5>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="c-fecha-hora d-flex flex-row">
                        <div class="c-fecha">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Fecha:</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fecha_Charla)</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="c-hora">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Hora:</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hora_Charla)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />

                    <h5 class="card-title">Sede:</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sede_Charla)</p>

                    <hr />

                    <h5 class="card-title">Dirección:</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lugar_Charla)</p>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="btn-incribirse d-flex flex-row">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Inscribirse", "CrearInteresado", new {
                                                                                   id = item.ID_Charla,
                                                                                   titulo = item.titulo_Charla,
                                                                                   descripcion = item.descrip_Charla,
                                                                                   fecha = item.fecha_Charla,
                                                                                   hora = item.hora_Charla,
                                                                                   direccion = item.lugar_Charla
                                                                               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        } 

    </div>

</div>

<!--LUEGO SE DEBE DE CAMBIAR EL TAMAÑO DEBIDO A QUE SE VA A ELIMINAR EL ENLACE INSCRIBIRSE-->
<style>

    form{
        height: 65px;
    }

    .c-dependencia, .c-meses{
        width: 49%;
    }

    i {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .titulo-charla-externo {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }

    .container-principal {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .container-lista {
        max-width: 1120px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .c-fecha-hora{
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    .c-fecha {

    }

    .c-hora{
        margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .btn-incribirse{
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .btn {
        padding: 6px 40px;
    }

    .card {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: no estoy seguro, pero intentaste sin las llaves ? solo es una linea la que esta dentro del if, funciona sin las llaves ?

Comment: Ahora lo compruebo :)

Comment: FUNCIONO!!!! gracias amigo @JhohanDavid

Comment: Pero aún me quede con la duda de cuál es la sintaxis correcta para realizar condicionales.